# Which is faster on row insert: SQL Server stored procedure or C# Server side code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a table that manages categories in a nested set model, and on each new row insertion, the whole table need to be updated.

For performance issues, I want to know if it's better to:

- Write triggers and stored procedures that fire on row inserts and manage the table

OR

- Write C# methods that are called by the main insert function?

Comment: I would think that doing it in SQL would be faster, as it would be one less trip.  Can't say for 100% though.

Comment: If you are inserting many rows, I suggest considering BulkInsert in C#.

Comment: The main advantage of using a stored procedure is you can add a unique ID to each row which isn't possible when creating the ID number from c#.  The stored procedure is usually faster because the SQL server is more efficient at parsing the SQL string than the Net Library.

Comment: SQL. They are both being fired at Run time. so `SQL == C# Methods` But SQL Stored Procedures already completed its calculation while Method C# has not so `SQL >= C#`

Comment: It depends, on a lot of factors

Comment: Avoid `triggers` like the plague that they are. For a simple, simple database, maybe it's ok. But as soon as you get into complex relationships, and you add in triggers to control different things, you will start to feel like a clown juggling a dozen flaming bowling pins. No lie!

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer to this question. Generally speaking, code contained in a stored procedure is faster than code from ADO.NET.

That being said, stored procedures and triggers have cached execution plans (so do ad-hoc queries from ADO.NET, but they work a bit differently). Execution plans are basically road maps for what algorithms the SQL server should use to perform join operations. As a stored procedure or trigger gets more complex, it's execution plan gets more complex. A single complex stored procedure may also end up with more than one execution plan, depending on the parameters passed to it. 
What can happen when a stored procedure gets very complex is that the SQL server can start choosing sub-optimal execution plans that actually work terribly, and your code can suddenly become very very slow. When this happens, the ADO.NET code ends up being faster, because it usually involves multiple small execution plans instead of one big one.

In general, when I have a situation like yours, I will choose to use stored procedures that do only a few things. If you start having to make more and more  updates as your business requirements change, and your stored procedure gets longer and longer, it is best to break that procedure into multiple procedures.

I would skip the triggers entirely. Triggers make it very difficult to reason about a system. They are nearly impossible to debug, and the set you up for surprises down the road.

It is a little bit of a code smell that you have to update the entire table when a row is inserted. If these inserts are happening frequently, you are going to have terrible performance issues. I would look for a way to better normalize your data so that this doesn't have to happen, if at all possible.

Comment: `code contained in a stored procedure is faster than code from ADO.NET` This is not true in any way. Execution will take exactly the same steps and performance will be the same. The only argument you can make is that transmitting a longer SQL string takes a few microseconds more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, the logic of the Nested Set model is that is very dynamic. Taxing on writes, but faster on reads than an usual Hierarchical Tree model.

Comment: I'm not claiming that stored procedures are faster because they magically have better execution plans. They're faster because they reduce round trips to the database, until they're slower because they're super complex.

Comment: The benefits of controlling and centralizing your insert in a stored proc will be of more benefit than any performance benefit between the two.   You will be able to control and change insert behavior without redistributing and re-compiling your client code.  You can change the stored proc only and be more flexible.